# Hibernate ordering

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the Vehicles class and mapping file for it and i want to get all rows from vehicles table ordered by ID desc (I also need the same for my other tables).

I got the following code:

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
tx = session.beginTransaction();

q = session.createQuery("from Vehicles order by ID DESC");

    for (Iterator it=q.iterate(); it.hasNext();){
         //some logic
    }
```

But my set isn't ordered by ID and each time it has a different order like RAND() or something. I was wondering what is the easiest way to keep the functionality and just to add order by clause because I have the same syntax on many places...

Comment: Can you turn on logging or set show_sql = true in your config so you can see what the generated sql looks like?  It should be obvious if it's missing the order by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try after "q = session.createQuery(...);" part:

```
List results = q.list()
//loop through results
```

There is probably something wrong elsewhere, because "sort by id desc" part is correct. Check your database/mapping files if you have correct data types and if indexes are set properly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your vehicles class looks like this? I'm using JPA here because thats what I know...

```
class Vehicles {
    @Id
    @Column(name="vehicles_id")
    private int id;
    // other stuff here
}
```

I don't expect your session.createQuery to be different from mine so wouldn't something like this work?

```
Query q = session.createQuery("select v from Vehicles v order by v.id desc");
```

Also you could use criteria if you wanted yeah?

```
class Main {
    List<Vehicles> cars;
}

Criteria main = session.createCriteria(Main.class);
Criteria secondary = main.createCriteria("cars");
secondary.addOrder(Order.asc("id"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "from Vehicles v order by v.id desc"? Also another option is to add the comparable interface to the entity and then bring the list created by the query into a sortedset. That's typically what I do when I need to sort.

Comment: Yeas I did, not working...
Is there any other way because I will need a lot of time to add comparable interface to all my classes and I will need to do some other changes in code...